# awk: how do you ensure consistent column numbering when there are blank columns?

Tags: awk

`my_file` is like this:

```
SELECTED   NAME    AGE
*          adam    30
           bob     70
```

I'd like to output:

```
adam
bob
```

however, if I try: `cat my_file|awk '{print $2}'` it outputs

```
NAME
adam
70
```

Any suggestions on how you get `awk` to account for a blank column?

Comment: is it always 1st that could be empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",/^ +/?$1:$2,ORS)}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
NAME
adam
bob
```

Comment: That works. Not sure I understand the `printf` though!

Comment: @Snowcrash, thanks for selecting it right answer. In `printf` you could mention the type of variable which you are printing in this case I have mentoined `%s` which means to print string(s) and checking condition here `/^ +/` means if a line starts with space then `?` which tells condition is TRUE prints `$1` else `:` will print `$2`, let me know if this is clear now?

Comment: What's `ORS` for?

Comment: @Snowcrash, output record separator, by default its value is new line.

Answer (score 1):

with `gawk` field widths

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='11 8 3' '{print $2}' file

NAME
adam
bob
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything. I'm using `awk -version
awk version 20070501` on the Mac.

Comment: this is GNU `awk` specific, not supported in all `awk`s.